# Errors with formik registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, formik

I'm creating a study project with React, Typescript, Formik and Firebase, however, my code does not working properly. It's fine with authentication, it is creating users in firebase, but it is not redirecting me, clearing the form and not sending data to the firestore.

I would highly appreciate your help and explanation!

## Registration.tsx:

```js
import React from "react";

import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FormikHelpers } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

// Firebase

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { collection, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

// Navigate
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);

const Registration: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleRedirect = () => {
    navigate("/main");
  };

  const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email").required("Email is required"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("Password is required")
      .min(8, "Password must be at least 8 characters")
      .matches(
        /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]+$/,
        "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character"
      ),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string()
      .test("password-match", "Passwords must match", function (value) {
        return value === this.resolve(Yup.ref("password"));
      })
      .nullable()
      .required("Confirm Password is required"),
  });

  const registrationSubmit = async (
    values: typeof initialValues,
    { resetForm }: FormikHelpers<typeof initialValues>
  ) => {
    try {
      const { name, email, password } = values;

      if (name && email && password) {
        const userCredential = await firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        await userCredential.user?.updateProfile({ displayName: name });

        try {
          console.log(userCredential.user?.uid);

          const db = firebase.firestore();

          await db.collection("users").doc(userCredential.user?.uid).set({
            name,
            email,
            password,
          });

          console.log("Registration was successful");
          resetForm();
          navigate("/main");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error writing to Firestore:", error);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Please provide all required fields");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="page bg-teal-50">
      <div className="container flex flex-col justify-center align-center">
        <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800">
          Registration
        </h1>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={registrationSubmit}
        >
          {({ errors, touched }) => (
            <Form className="flex flex-col m-auto" autoComplete="off">
              <div className="flex mt-16 items-center justify-center flex-col ">
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  className={`w-64 h-12 text-gray-900 pl-4 outline-none border-solid border-2 rounded focus:border-teal-600 ${
                    errors.name && touched.name
                      ? "border-red-500"
                      : "border-teal-400"
                  }`}
                />{" "}
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="name"
                  component="p"
                  className="text-red-600 font-bold text-lg flex align-center mt-4"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex mt-4 items-center justify-center flex-col ">
                <Field
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  className={`w-64 h-12 text-gray-900 pl-4 outline-none border-solid border-2 rounded focus:border-teal-600 ${
                    errors.name && touched.name
                      ? "border-red-500"
                      : "border-teal-400"
                  }`}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="email"
                  component="p"
                  className="text-red-600 font-bold text-lg flex align-center mt-4"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex mt-4 items-center justify-center flex-col ">
                <Field
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  className={`w-64 h-12 text-gray-900 pl-4 outline-none border-solid border-2 rounded focus:border-teal-600 ${
                    errors.name && touched.name
                      ? "border-red-500"
                      : "border-teal-400"
                  }`}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="password"
                  component="p"
                  className="text-red-600 font-bold text-lg flex align-center mt-4"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex mt-4 items-center justify-center flex-col ">
                <Field
                  type="password"
                  id="confirmPassword"
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  className={`w-64 h-12 text-gray-900 pl-4 outline-none border-solid border-2 rounded focus:border-teal-600 ${
                    errors.name && touched.name
                      ? "border-red-500"
                      : "border-teal-400"
                  }`}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  component="p"
                  className="text-red-600 font-bold text-lg flex align-center mt-4"
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="bg-blue-500 w-32 h-12 cursor-pointer mt-8 m-auto text-white text-xl rounded hover:bg-blue-700 transition-colors duration-300"
              >
                Register
              </button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Registration;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to respond to your issue.
the Formik part looks ok to me, does it print something on submit?

PS: please remove your firebase configuration from the question, someone might try to break your stuff